# Files getting deleted as unstaged changes when checking out to another branch

Tags: git

After merge, I'm facing a weird problem where checking out to another branch causes unstaged changes - deletion of some files.

```
PS>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
PS>git checkout master_test
Switched to branch 'master_test'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master_test'.
PS>git status
On branch master_test
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master_test'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    Modules/CimCmdlets/CimCmdlets.psd1
        ...
```

Since it happens only when I do `git checkout`, I assume that files are deleted by git itself.
How do I determine why those files are getting deleted?

edit: There is no difference between files on those branches, including names. For example:
[image: WinMerge diff between folders]

Comment: Can you check that the branch you checked out doesn't have different casing on one of these files, like for instance you had `cimCmdlets.psd1` on one branch and `CimCmdlets.psd1` on the other branch (notice the case of the first letter in the filename is different).

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I double checked both manually and with WinMerge, they are identical.

Comment: Is `Modules` in the same Git repo, or in a submodule?

Comment: @joanis there are no submodules, everything is in the same repo

Comment: This is weird behaviour. It sounds like a bug to me, but I hope there is some other explanation!

Comment: If WinMerge is aimed at Windows (which seems logical from the name), WinMerge probably considers a file named `lowercase` to be the same as one named `LOWERCASE` (since Windows THINKS THAT THIS IS NOT SHOUTING :-) ) and therefore won't catch the problem that Git will suffer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Windows is case-insensitive by default, you likely have two files with the same name but different casing. Windows tools such as WinMerge cannot spot this because only one of the two files were checked out.

I'll demonstrate this on OS X which is also case-insensitive by default. I've created a Git repo on a case-sensitive volume with both `FOO` and `foo` files. Now I'm checking it out on a case-insensitive filesystem.

```
$ git clone /Volumes/case_sensitive/tmp/test
Cloning into 'test'...
done.
warning: the following paths have collided (e.g. case-sensitive paths
on a case-insensitive filesystem) and only one from the same
colliding group is in the working tree:

  'FOO'
  'foo'

$ ls
.git  foo

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   FOO

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

[The warning was added in 2.20.0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b878579ae755e3a9d200093ced59ada3eaafb08c).

You can get a true listing of files with `git ls-files`.

```
$ git ls-files
FOO
foo
```

We can fix this by renaming one file to something unique...

```
$ git mv foo foo2

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    renamed:    foo -> foo2

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    FOO
```

And now that it's out of the way we can checkout the other file.

```
$ git co FOO
Updated 1 path from the index

$ ls
.git  FOO  foo2

$ git st
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    renamed:    foo -> foo2
```

And after you've fixed any code that used `foo` to now use `foo2`, commit.